# Emacs evil-leader and evil-nerd-commenter conflict

Tags: vim, emacs, evil-mode

I'm using **evil-leader** and **evil-nerd-commenter**, but I don't like the nerd commenter way of using `,,` to comment lines (I use `,` to search backward when using `t` or `f`), so I changed it to `\\` as suggested in its page. But if I install **evil-leader**, it seems to conflict, since now when I hit `\\` it tells me `\ \ is undefined`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check README of https://github.com/redguardtoo/evil-nerd-commenter. This issue is totally resolved now.

If you don't like default key bindings which use "," as prefix, just don't call `(evilnc-default-hotkeys)` in your Emacs. That's it!

Set up your evil-leader as usual.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I want to use \\ to comment a line, not `,,` since I use `,` to search backward in line after using `f` or `t`.

Comment: sorry, it's in readme, but not at the bottom, ",," is used to comment evil text objects,(setq evilnc-hotkey-comment-operator "\\") to modify that operator.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, that's the option I use. That is **not** the problem. The problem is that when I install a plugin named **evil-leader**, it messes up with **evil-nerd-commenter** and "\\" will stop working.

Comment: check its README, I updated doc, adding some sample setup, at the bottom of the page, basically you just need assign your own hotkey for the command "evilnc-comment-operator". if you still have any issue, report the bug at github page